# Ansible replacing special characters within string with jinja2 (ASCII encoding)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to pass password that may contain special character, e.g, %, @, &... to API call via shell task in my ansible playbook. I used quotes' ' or \ to escape the special characters. But not all of them are working, e.g, %.... So I used the 'replace' in my playbook to replace these characters with ASCII encoding according to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP if I find them in string. THe playbook looks like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_password: "{{ my_pw | replace('%','%25')|replace('@','%40')|replace..... }}"
```

This works. But obviously it is not the best solution, as I have to list all special characters here to make sure I won't miss any. I am thinking of creating jinja2 templates to map all special characters based on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP. So I can just call this template when I need it in my playbook. I'm new to jinja2. How would I achieve this or is this even possible to achieve? I am on ansible 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is [`| urlencode`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#urlencode)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: encoded password is {{ my_pw | urlencode }}
    vars:
      my_password: "alpha+beta/charlie@example.com"
```

emits

`alpha%2Bbeta/charlie%40example.com`

but as the docs mention, if you need the `/` encoded, you'll want to add `| replace("/", "%2F")` to the end

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel. However, it does not work for me. I am getting 'no filter named 'urlencode'. My ansible is very old. It probably does not have this function

Comment: Then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65415527/edit) and include those details, otherwise no one would guess you're on an ancient version of ansible and subsequently we cannot provide a link to the relevant jinja2 docs for your version

Comment: Because [they didn't pin the jinja2 version](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.4.6.0-1/requirements.txt#L6), merely reinstalling `pip install ansible==2.4.6.0` will bring `jinja2==2.11.2` with it, and poof, you're back in the modern(?) world